# Rails cache_counter not decrementing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a cache counter setup for a Posts class on the comments field. Posts have many comments, and a comment belongs to a post.

If I add a new comment to a post and save, the counter gets incremented, but if I delete an individual comment, the counter is not touched. Is this not provided automatically, or do I have to roll me own decrementor when working with counter_cache?

Rails 2.3.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you deleting the comment?

You should know that `ActiveRecord::Base delete` and `destroy` are not the same thing. Delete won't go through any callbacks, so it won't update the cache counter.